# Invalid column name 'TABLETYPE' in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Tags: sql-server

The following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLETYPE = 'VIEW';
```

Throws 'Invalid column name 'TABLENAME'. But the column is shown in query.
I tried to replace 'TABLENAME' for 'tablename' and nothing worked.
I read that this could be a InteliSense cache problem, that is needs to be refreshed. But I execute statements like this in my application, so unless I can be able to do it via sql, that is not really an option for me.
Correct me if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Table Type' column has an underscore in it, so you'll want to use:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW';
```

Comment: I can not believe the the underscore was not showing in the query. Thanks.

Comment: No worries and welcome to the SO community! Please consider marking the answer as 'accepted' if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Eagle Eye.  Never saw the missing underscore  +1